# Glass shader. How can I get rid of the reflection in the glass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, glass, reflection

I have two planes with a glass shader one after another, and the object is reflected in the glass, how can I get rid of the reflection in the glass?
https://disk.yandex.kz/i/5t71DmYOupy7jQ

Comment: Reflactions are what makes glass look like glass.

Comment: but my glass somehow behaves like a mirror)

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Are you looking for no glossy reflections at all (only refraction) or just less strong gloss?

Answer (score 2):

Glass is reflective, so if you want to completely get rid of the reflections it won't look like glass anymore.  This can be done by using a *refraction* shader which only passes light through and does not reflect any rays.  If you want to just tone down the reflections you can mix a refraction shader with a glossy shader sharing the same parameters.

[image]

Below is shown an example of 100% glass, 20% glass and 0% glass respectively.

[image]

This may make your render look undesirable in other manners however as it will no longer be very physically accurate.  If this is the case, I suggest playing with the angle of your camera and/or whatever is being reflected in order to have it not block your view (as you may sometimes do in real life to look through a glaring object).